# Converting NumPy floats to ints without loss of precision

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am working on a vision algorithm with OpenCV in Python. One of the components of it requires comparing points in color-space, where the x and y components are not integers. Our list of points is stored as ndarray with dtype = float64, and our numbers range from -10 to 10 give or take.

Part of our algorithm involves running a convex hull on some of the points in this space, but `cv2.convexHull()` requires an ndarray with dtype = int.

Given the narrow range of the values we are comparing, simple truncation causes us to lose ~60 bits of information. Is there any way to have numpy directly interpret the float array as an int array? Since the scale has no significance, I would like all 64 bits to be considered.

Is there any defined way to separate the exponent from the mantissa in a numpy float, without doing bitwise extraction for every element?

Comment: Multiply your float array by 1000, pass it in, divide the output by 1000? So if your number was 12.123, pass in 12123 as an integer.

Comment: FYI: [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) accepts a floating point array.

Comment: Floating point has 53 bits of significance, not 64 - the other bits are used for the exponent and sign.

Comment: P.S. I can see why a range of -10 to 10 is not precise enough, but for color work you really don't need that much more precision. Multiplying by 100 would probably work.

Comment: Another FYI: *"I would like all 64 bits to be considered."* From a bit of googling (I'm not an OpenCV expert), it looks like the largest integer type available for OpenCV arrays is signed 32 bit, so there is no point in trying to maintain the information in all 64 (or 53) bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Part of our algorithm involves running a convex hull on some of the points in this space, but cv2.convexHull() requires an ndarray with dtype = int."

cv2.convexHull() also accepts numpy array with float32 number.

Try using `cv2.convexHull(numpy.array(a,dtype = 'float32'))` where a is a list of dimension n*2 (n = no. of points).